# A question about integration by parts in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $h \in L^2(\mu)$ and $\mu = \rho(x)dx$, where $dx$ is Lebesgue measure and $\rho(x)$ is $C^1$. Also, $b(x) = (b_1(x), \cdots, b_n(x))$ is also a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, does the following integration by parts hold?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} b \cdot \nabla(h^2)\rho \,dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h^2 \nabla \cdot (b\rho)\,dx$$

The issue for me is, of course, the boundary term. Is there any reason to say the boundary term is $0$? If not, could it hold if we impose some restrictions on $b(x)$ or $h$, such as $h$ is a Schwartz function? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You have to write your integral as a limit of integrals on the ball $\{\lvert x\rvert \le R\}$. Apply the integration by parts there, then let $R\to \infty$. Maybe the boundary terms vanish (it should be the case with suitable decay assumptions).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your answer. Yes, of course, I assumed we should do the limit process. So, I am wondering if the boundary terms vanish as $R \to \infty$. Is $h\in L^2(\mu)$ enough to show it or at least does it have to belong to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is Schwartz then the answer is affirmative, but you seem to want $h\in L^2$ only. That's not enough. Having $k:=h^2$ in $L^1$ does not guarantee anything about $\nabla k$. It could be a tiny but highly oscillating function, say 
$$
k(x)=\frac{\sin(e^{|x|})}{(1+|x|^2)^{100}}.$$
With this function, your right-hand side does make sense, but the left-hand side does not.

The right assumption is $h^2\in W^{1,1}$. With this one, your formula is true. Proof: establish the formula for a Schwartz $h$, then extend by density, using the fact that both sides are continuous with respect to the $W^{1,1}$ norm.

> **EDIT**. How to prove that the boundary term vanishes, provided $h$ decays sufficiently rapidly?

Here's a way. Integration by parts on the ball $\{|x|\le R\}$ yields 
$$
\int_{\{|x|\le R\}} \boldsymbol b \cdot \nabla(h^2)\rho \,dx = \int_{\{|x|=R\}} \boldsymbol{b}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\, h^2 \rho\, dS - \int_{\{|x|\le R\}} h^2 \nabla \cdot (\boldsymbol b\rho)\,dx,$$
where $\boldsymbol{n}$ denotes the unit normal vector. We then have the estimate
$$\left\lvert \int_{\{|x|=R\}} \boldsymbol{b}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\, h^2 \rho\, dS \right\rvert\le C_{\boldsymbol b, \rho}\sup_{|x|=R} (h^2(x))\left\lvert \int_{|x|=R}\, dS\right\rvert=C_{\boldsymbol b, \rho}\sup_{|x|=R} (h^2(x))R^{n-1}.$$

Thus, if $h^2(x)=o(|x|^{-(n-1)})$, the boundary term vanishes. This is certainly the case if $h$ is compactly supported, or Schwartz.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Actually, this is from one of Cedric Villani's books. In this book, many things assumed to be trivial, but as a novice, I am trying to understand it one by one.

Here, he just assumes $h \in H = L^2(\mu)$ and $\rho$ is an equilibrium measure (which I forgot to mention.) Also, $Bh = b(x) \cdot \nabla h$, an unbounded operator.

I have two further questions/favors. First, could you show in detail how the equality  holds when $h$ is a Schwarts function when $b$ is just a $C^1$ function? Second, if it holds when $h \in W^{1,1}$ by desity, that means

Comment: it holds for the weak derivative of $(\nabla h^2)$, right? I'd really appreciate it if you'd help me. Thanks so much :)

Comment: I've also added a photo of the statement in case I missed some information. It'd very helpful if you'd answer me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I understand most of it, except for one thing. If $h$ is compactly supported, then $C_{\textbf{b}, \rho} \sup\limits_{\vert x \vert =R } (h^2(x)) R^{n-1} \to 0$. However, if it's just Schwarts and $C_{\textbf{b}, \rho}$ is not bounded, then $C_{\textbf{b}, \rho} \sup\limits_{\vert x \vert =R } (h^2(x)) R^{n-1}$ might not go to $0$, since  $C_{\textbf{b}, \rho}$ depends on $x$ too. Do we have to impose more restrictions on $\textbf{b}$ and $\rho$, too?

Comment: Oh, yes, I assumed $b$ and $\rho$ were bounded. If they are not, then $h$ must decay sufficiently fast to compensate. A compactly supported $h$ will be OK for all $b$s and $\rho$s.

Comment: I see. Also, if that equality holds for Schwartz functions, then it holds for $h\in W^{1,1}$ by density. However, in this case, it is in the sense of weak derivatives, since $\nabla (h^2)$ only makes sense weakly..?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, can I ask you one more question about this? If $h \in H^1$ instead of $h^2 \in W^{1,1}$, can we still use the density argument? In other words, even if $h \in H^1$, we cannot guarantee that $h^2 \in W^{1,1}$?

Comment: Yes, but that is easy. Since $h\in L^2$, assuming that $\nabla h\in L^2$ we have that $$\nabla(h^2)=2h\nabla h \in L^1, $$ hence if $h\in H^1$ the formula holds.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me first! Actually, the tricky part for me is to show $\nabla(h^2) = 2h \nabla h$. We have a sequence $\{h_n\} \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $h_n \to h$ and $\partial_{x_i} h_n \to \partial_{x_i} h$. Accordinly, we have $\int (h_n)^2 \partial_{x_i}\phi' = \int 2h_n \partial_{x_i}h_n \phi$. If we want to show each side passes to the limit using dominated convergence Theorem to show $\nabla(h^2) = 2h\nabla h$, I think we need some kind of $L^\infty$ boundedness for $h_n$ and $\partial_{x_i} h_n$. Does that make sense? I try to think rigorously.

Comment: You have such boundedness; it is encoded precisely in the condition $h\in H^1$. Use that $\phi\in L^\infty$ and that $h_n\to h$ and $\partial_i h_n\to \partial_i h$ in $L^2$, thus their product converges in $L^1$.

Comment: (LHS):  $\vert \int h_n^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi -  \int h^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi \vert \le \int \vert h_n^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi -  h^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi \vert  \le \Vert h_n^2 - h^2 \Vert \Vert \partial_{x_i}\phi \Vert \to 0$ since $h_n$, $h \in L^1$. (RHS): $\vert \int h_n\partial_{x_i}h_n \phi - \int h\partial_{x_i}h \phi \vert \le \int \vert h_n\partial_{x_i}h_n \phi - h\partial_{x_i}h \phi \vert \le \Vert h_n \partial_{x_i}h_n - h \partial_{x_i}h\Vert_1 \Vert \phi\Vert_1 \to 0$, since $h_n\partial_{x_i}h_n$, $h \partial_{x_i}h \in L^1$. Is that what you meant? :)

Comment: Actually, since I only know that if $u$, $v\in W^{1,p} \cap L^\infty$, then $uv  \in W^{1,p} \cap L^\infty$, I thought we might need the $L^\infty$ boundedness. However, $H^2$ is a little different. I really thank you for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, I meant using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which looks like what you did. You should specify what the norms are, though; $\lVert h_n^2-h^2\rVert$ is $L^1$, while $\|\partial_i \phi\rVert$ is $L^\infty$.

Comment: Oh, I made several major typos. $\int \vert h_n^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi - h^2 \partial_{x_i} \phi \vert \le \Vert h_n^2 - h^2 \Vert_1 \Vert \partial_{x_i} \phi \Vert_\infty$. Also, $\int \vert h_n \partial_{x_i} h_n\phi - h \partial_{x_i} h \phi \vert \le \Vert h_n \partial_{x_i}h_n - h\partial_{x_i} h\Vert_1 \Vert \phi\Vert_{\infty}$. Actually this is more like Holder's inequality rather than Cauchy-Schwarz you meant... However, is it still okay? :)

Comment: Oh yeah, it's Holder, not Cauchy Schwarz. Anyway.